# How to display runtimepath value in echo or echomsg?

Tags: options, runtimepath

I have modified the `'runtimepath'` in my `.vimrc` file.
As I am having problems of not found files, I would like to display the `runtimepath` value in an `:echo` or `:echomsg`

I already know about the existence of `:scriptnames` and the possibility of checking the value with `:set runtimepath`, but I specifically need to display it with `:echo` or `:echomsg` commands.

I have already tried, without success, the following:

- `:echo runtimepath`
- `:echo expand(runtimepath)`
- `:echo expand('runtimepath')`

Comment: Nothing that can't be found with a simple `:help :echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Everyting that is set using `:set` is an option in vim.
Options are described in the help between single quotes, like in `:h 'runtimepath'`

If you check the documentation page `:h after-directory`, it is said:

> More entries are added when using |packages|.  If it gets very long
> then `:set rtp` will be truncated, use `:echo &rtp` to see the full
> string.

Therefore, the answer to the question is:

`:echo &runtimepath`

As suggested by @d-ben-knoble in the comments, this approach creates a new buffer and reports in a much more legible way as each path is in a different line

`:new | put =split(&runtimepath, ',')`

Output is like

```
C:\Users\myusername/vimfiles
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim90
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim90\pack\dist\opt\matchit
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after
C:\Users\myusername/vimfiles/after
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way that may be easier depending on the situation.

Sometimes I do things like this with the expression register (`:h @=`) knowing that settings can be accessed from expressions using a leading `&` (from `:h expression-syntax` in the `expr10` section in my version)

While in insert mode:

```
<c-r>=&runtimepath<cr>
```

You could make it "clean" by combining with the `split` in  [@aturegano's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41953/44238):

```
<c-r>=split(&runtimepath, ',')<cr>
```

Comment: This is useful in Insert mode! The other answer has the benefit of being readily accessible in Normal mode, which is the mode I'm in normally :)